# How to pass in the Context for the activity, along with a string containing the public license key

Tags: android, eclipse, android-context

I am following the guidelines of google to initiate a connection with google play I do not know how to "pass in the Context for the activity" and  "with a string containing the public license key"

Here what I have done so far. I am not a pro programmer.

IabHelper mHelper;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey;
       mHelper = new IabHelper(Homepage.this, door);

       mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
           public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
              if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                 // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                 Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
              }            
                 // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!  
           }
        });
```

Comment: I think currently your code works well. What is your question?

Comment: I am a beginner, I dont know how to make a string that contains a public license key?, I dont think it is the same a xml string. I wanted to assure that I have passed the context to the activity correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` OR  `Homepage.this` instead of `this`

For more info refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) link

Comment: Thank you, is this all what I need to do to pass the context?

Comment: It was useful but it did not answer my full question so I cant accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is below:

```
public class Homepage extends Activity {
IabHelper mHelper;


@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = this.getResource().getString(R.string.base64EncodedPublicKey);
       mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
```

You can define your license String in `res\value\string.xml`,like this:
<string name="base64EncodedPublicKey">your license string</string>

Comment: If it is a xml string then I should put it as R.id.base64EncodedPublicKey   am I right?

Comment: you should use R.string.base64EncodedPublicKey, I have updated the answer